# Is there a way to add more properties to "Worklight Settings"?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way to add more properties to "Worklight Settings" ?. I want to store some values  so that customers can change it and in the code we can read those values at client side.

Or Is it possible to build a similar ui ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the UI yourself, writing the customer setting either in the  user preferences (see the `WL.Client.setUserPref`, `WL.Client.getUserInfo` and other API or in a local storage with JSONStore).

Comment: For future readers: `or in a local storage with JSONStore`. Note that local storage there means 'inside the local file system of the device' **not** [HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: thanks, Should I write the UI specific to each environment (native) or should be from the server ?. Please suggest. Is it possible to share some samples.

Comment: It seems that you are no very familiar with Worklight. You should go over the Getting started with IBM Worklight http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html